# How to display footer only on first page (birt conditional display footer)

Tags: footer, birt

I am trying to display a footer for only the first Page on birt 4.8. Everytime when I do it, it does not generate properly. can you give me some hints.

I used:

```
if (BirtComp.equalTo(pageNumber, 1))
{
this.getStyle().display = "NONE";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post how you attempted to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your layout requirements, consider using two different master pages, one for the first page, one for the rest of the pages, let's call them `MasterPageFirst` and `MasterPageRest`.
Then, in the page break property dialog of your layout objects, you can explicitly set `MasterPageFirst` for the first top-level layout element and `MasterPageRest` for the first layout element that should be displayed on page 2.

If you still want to use page variables, keep in mind that they only work when the report is generated with separate `RunTask` and `RenderTask`.
I try to avoid using page variables and can't help you in this regard. I can't really help you in this regard but I doubt you are using them correctly.